# append text to textarea on specific line after \n

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I wanted to append text to a `textarea` on a specific dynamic line. So for instance I have a list of `checkboxes`, and their `id` ranges from `0-i`. Now I also have a `textarea` with the exact same number of lines as there are `id` ranges. So if a user clicks on checkbox id `2`, I'd like the third line in my `textarea` to append some text.

Would you have to split the `textarea` first like this

`var todolines = $('#todoListSave').val().split('\n');` and then append text individually or is there a better approach?

Comment: you mean something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/5bktL6sp/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like

```js
var $text = $('textarea');
//to initiate the value not required if the textarea value is already given
$text.val(new Array($(':checkbox').length + 1).join('\n'));

$(':checkbox').change(function() {
  var split = $text.val().split('\n');
  if (this.checked) {
    split[this.id] += this.value;
  } else {
    var regex = new RegExp(RegExp.escape(this.value) + '$');
    split[this.id] = split[this.id].replace(regex, '')
  }
  $text.val(split.join('\n'));
})

if (!RegExp.escape) {
  RegExp.escape = function(value) {
    return value.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
  };
}
```

```css
textarea {
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="0" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="1" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" id="2" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" id="3" value="4" />
<input type="checkbox" id="4" value="5" />
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: Well, actually this seems to overwrite the text already in the textarea. Anyway to append the text?

Comment: if unchecked then what to do

Comment: Almost, but the checkbox value is now at the end of the string and unchecking doesn't make the value go away...